# Distinguish between lists of lists and lists using pattern matching

Tags: haskell

Basicallly I want to do something like this: (Which does't work)

```
g2 (x:xs) = x
g2 ((x:xs):ys) = x
```

So if g2 gets a list it should extract the first element of the list and if it is a list of lists it is supposed to extract the first element in the first list.

Comment: I think you reason one meta-level too high. Functions have *types* to reason about types, patterns to reason about *values*. So at the moment you write `g2`, you already know what the type is. I think you here want a *polymorphic* function.

Comment: So what type does `g2` have? Try giving it a signature and you should see that you're describing two different functions (`head` and `head . head`).

Comment: Thank you guys for clarifying . Seems like I need to find an other way to solve my problem.

Comment: @Luca9984 You may need a tree. Take a look in Data.Tree. A Node holds a data item and a list of sub-nodes. This is how you deal with data structures that in other languages might be handled by heterogenous lists of (items and lists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on what Willem Van Onsem said, if you annotate your functions, you get:

```
-- aka `head`
g2 :: [a] -> a
g2 (x:xs) = x

-- aka `head . head`
g2' :: [[a]] -> a
g2' ((x:xs):ys) = x
```

These cannot be the same function, because if `g2` sometimes takes as input `[a]` and sometimes takes as input `[[a]]`, then GHC will try to unify `a = [a]`, which GHC calls an infinite type (`a = [a]` ⇒ `a = [[a]]` ⇒ `a = [[[...a...]]]` infinitely).

---

When you want to feed a function something that is sometimes a list and sometimes a list of lists, Haskell handles this using sum types, e.g.

```
g2 :: Either [a] [[a]] -> a
g2 (Left (x:xs)) = x
g2 (Right ((x:xs):ys)) = x
```

and before using this function on any input, you have to know which one it is (e.g. `Left "Hello"`, `Right ["Hello", "World"]`). But beware that all of the `g2`s so far have been [*partial*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions), which is bad. E.g. calling `g2 (Left [])`, `g2 (Right [])` or `g2 [Right [[]]` will crash.

---

If instead of a list you had an n-ary tree ([`Data.Tree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Tree.html)),

```
import Data.Tree
```

then this lets you nest lists arbitrarily:

```
g2 :: Tree a -> a
g2 (Tree x []) = x
g2 (Tree _ (Tree x : _)) = x
```

or you can even get the first element of the first tree with no sub-forests, or at most `n` deep:

```
g :: Int -> Tree a -> a
g 0 (Tree x _) = x
g _ (Tree x []) = x
g n (Tree _x t) = g (n-1) t

g2 :: Tree a -> a
g2 = g 1
```

Because of the way `Tree a` is defined, this kind of tree cannot be empty, and so this `g2` isn't partial. Unlike `[[a]]`, `Tree a` has both an `x` at the top-level of the tree (e.g. `_x` above) and possibly an `x` another level in.

---

If you *(a)* intend for your input only to be nested two deep, *(b)* the notion of a "parent value" doesn't make sense in your case, and *(c)* you want to guarantee at the type level that the `x` you're looking for will exist, perhaps it is better to compose [`Data.List.NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html):

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty

type NestedNonEmpty a = Either (NonEmpty a) (NonEmpty (NonEmpty a))

g2 :: NestedNonEmpty a -> a
g2 (Left (x :| _)) = x
g2 (Right ((x :| _) :| _)) = x
```

You could then use it like:

```
onetwothree :: NonEmpty Int
onetwothree = 1 :| 2 : 3 : []

t1, t2 :: NestedNonEmpty Int
t1 = Left onetwothree
t2 = Right $ onetwothree :| fmap (+3) onetwothree : []

demo1, demo2 :: Int
demo1 = g2 t1 -- 1
demo2 = g2 t2 -- 1
```

But since this data type is overly specific, perhaps it is good to revise what your input will actually look like and consequently what its type then must be. Since you commented that you'd have to find another way to solve your problem, perhaps ask a question with that problem in focus to not make this an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). :-)

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer. I managed to solve my problem by splitting my my function into multiple functions as you suggested.